# Recovering vmware snapshot missing in snapshot mgr

Tags: vmware-workstation

On my SharePoint development VM I have a snapshot missing in snapshot manager but the files are still in the folder. Is there a way to get that snapshot back? Even at the cost of losing the other two snapshots would be fine. the 000003 series from 11/23 are the snapshot in question. I would like to avoid losing the development set up and my source code. At a minimum is there a way to mount the unavailable snapshot to extricate the source?

If it helps, the folder looks like so.

```
06/11/2013  04:45 PM    <DIR>          caches
10/25/2013  10:12 AM             8,684 nvram
12/02/2013  03:44 PM                 0 snaps.txt
11/20/2012  04:37 PM                 0 vmmcores-2.gz
11/20/2012  05:01 PM            86,016 vmmcores-3.gz
10/25/2013  10:12 AM           279,342 vmware-0.log
10/11/2013  03:28 AM           262,452 vmware-1.log
09/09/2013  02:22 AM           261,598 vmware-2.log
10/28/2013  10:27 AM           244,228 vmware.log
10/28/2013  10:27 AM       135,266,304 Windows Server 2008 R2 x64-000001-s001.vmdk
... 
10/28/2013  10:27 AM           327,680 Windows Server 2008 R2 x64-000001-s233.vmdk
10/28/2013  10:27 AM            15,221 Windows Server 2008 R2 x64-000001.vmdk
07/05/2013  02:44 PM       430,637,056 Windows Server 2008 R2 x64-000002-s001.vmdk
...
07/05/2013  02:44 PM           327,680 Windows Server 2008 R2 x64-000002-s233.vmdk
07/05/2013  02:43 PM            15,240 Windows Server 2008 R2 x64-000002.vmdk
10/28/2013  11:08 AM    <DIR>          Windows Server 2008 R2 x64-000002.vmdk.lck
11/23/2012  11:05 AM         9,961,472 Windows Server 2008 R2 x64-000003-s001.vmdk
...
11/23/2012  11:05 AM           327,680 Windows Server 2008 R2 x64-000003-s233.vmdk
11/23/2012  10:55 AM            15,221 Windows Server 2008 R2 x64-000003.vmdk
12/02/2013  03:08 PM           327,680 Windows Server 2008 R2 x64-000004-s001.vmdk
...
12/02/2013  03:08 PM           327,680 Windows Server 2008 R2 x64-000004-s233.vmdk
12/02/2013  03:08 PM            15,166 Windows Server 2008 R2 x64-000004.vmdk
10/25/2013  09:09 AM     6,442,450,944 Windows Server 2008 R2 x64-09d799d1.vmem
12/02/2013  12:58 PM    <DIR>          Windows Server 2008 R2 x64-09d799d1.vmem.lck
10/28/2013  10:27 AM       148,079,156 Windows Server 2008 R2 x64-09d799d1.vmss
02/03/2013  06:36 PM     2,048,131,072 Windows Server 2008 R2 x64-s001.vmdk
...
02/03/2013  06:36 PM           393,216 Windows Server 2008 R2 x64-s233.vmdk
11/20/2012  04:55 PM     8,589,934,592 Windows Server 2008 R2 x64-Snapshot4.vmem
11/20/2012  04:55 PM       147,015,328 Windows Server 2008 R2 x64-Snapshot4.vmsn
11/23/2012  10:51 AM    12,884,901,888 Windows Server 2008 R2 x64-Snapshot5.vmem
11/23/2012  10:51 AM       146,634,244 Windows Server 2008 R2 x64-Snapshot5.vmsn
02/03/2013  06:40 PM     8,589,934,592 Windows Server 2008 R2 x64-Snapshot6.vmem
02/03/2013  06:40 PM       149,164,491 Windows Server 2008 R2 x64-Snapshot6.vmsn
07/10/2013  03:42 PM            32,499 Windows Server 2008 R2 x64-Snapshot8.vmsn
02/03/2013  10:40 AM            13,862 Windows Server 2008 R2 x64.vmdk
10/28/2013  11:08 AM    <DIR>          Windows Server 2008 R2 x64.vmdk.lck
12/02/2013  03:09 PM               916 Windows Server 2008 R2 x64.vmsd
12/02/2013  03:08 PM             4,402 Windows Server 2008 R2 x64.vmx
03/21/2013  12:12 PM             3,053 Windows Server 2008 R2 x64.vmxf
        1190 File(s) 113,523,393,103 bytes
           6 Dir(s)  104,812,756,992 bytes free
```

I am using workstation 9.0.3 build-1410761

I tried to mount the vmdk as a drive and received the error:

```
The parent virtual disk has been modified since the child was created. 
The content ID of the parent virtual disk does not match the 
corresponding parent content ID in the child.
```

I have tried to force the CID's to match with no success.

I don't know when the the snapshot went rouge but it was **before** the last backups. So all the backups have the same issue.

Comment: To be absolutely safe, you should create a standalone duplicate of a vm's disk and desired snapshot and keep it separately, so this doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Oh crap! My last post was removed by admin.

Just found these:

https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/57015
https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1002310

I am hopeful these will help. Could be the solution. I am trying. If I don't come back, it means these worked!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.